# How to add transition into Javascript document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";

Tags: javascript, css, html, transition

How can I add transition to `document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";` I am currently working on a registration form in which if one input is of a certain value the other div is hidden but it looks so rough, Is there a way to add transitions into the following JS ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
        }
        function hideshow(which){
            if (!document.getElementById)
                return
                if (which.style.display=="block")
                which.style.display="block"
                else
                    which.style.display="block"
                    }


        function myFunction1() {
            document.getElementById("myDIV2").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hamza, why not using jQuery ?

Comment: @Sami I did it via JQuery, check my answer for further information, but I wanted to see if there is anyway to do it with simple js.

Answer (score 0):

Create functions with parameters like

```
function hideDiv(div_id) {
        document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "none";
}

function showDiv(div_id) {
        document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to make a nice transition is to set `style.display= "none"` *after* you perform some kind of animation that removes the element from view.

You could:

- Fade it out (set `opacity` to 0 - fade it with `transition` in CSS)
- Slide it up/down/left/right (animation library or fancy CSS)
- Do some other fancier animation (like bounce, shrink etc.)

**Then**, set `style.display = "none"`

The easiest way to do this (in my opinion) is with an animation library. I personally recommend [VelocityJS](https://julian.com/) because you don't need jQuery to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anyway to do that with simple js, however I did it easily using JQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#myDIV").show();

$(document).on('click', '.married' , function() {

    if (this.value == "never_married"){            
        $("#myDIV").hide('slow');           
    } else {
        $("#myDIV").show('slow');           
    }       
})
```

});

Answer (score -1):

The reason is `display` isn't animated, setting it from `block` to `none` won't give you the result you're looking for.

A nice way to do this is to use CSS alongside JavaScript for the transition.

Add `Transition` to your `myDIV` style such as:

```
#myDIV {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s ease;
}

#myDIV.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
```

Then with JavaScript apply the `hidden` class to `#myDiv` and you'll get your animation.
Once the animation has finished then set `el.style.display = 'none';` to make it disappear completely from view.